# How would you validate a checkbox in ASP.Net MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Using MVC2, I have a simple ViewModel that contains a bool field that is rendered on the view as a checkbox.  I would like to validate that the user checked the box.  The [Required] attribute on my ViewModel doesn't seem to do the trick.  I believe this is because the unchecked checkbox form field is not actually transmitted back during the POST, and therefore the validation doesn't run on it.

Is there a standard way to handle checkbox "required" validation in MVC2? or do I have to write a custom validator for it?  I suspect the custom validator won't get executed either for the reason mentioned above.  Am I stuck checking for it explicitly in my controller?  That seems messy...

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Scott

EDIT FOR CLARITY: As pointed out in comments below, this is a "agree to our terms" type of checkbox, and therefore "not checked" is a valid answer, so I'm really looking for an "is checked" validation.

Comment: Is this an "I accept the terms of the license agreement" type of checkbox?  The [Required] attribute doesn't work because an unchecked checkbox is a valid value (false).

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that, and if they don't check it, we're just redisplaying the same view with a validation message that you must accept the terms to continue.  I see your point about false being "valid" though.

Comment: The answer here has a nice way of doing it that works with the client validators: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934032/mvc3-make-checkbox-required-via-jquery-validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934032/mvc3-make-checkbox-required-via-jquery-validate)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

a custom validator is the way to go. I'll post my code which I used to validate that the user accepts the terms ...

```
public class BooleanRequiredToBeTrueAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this validate client side as well?

Comment: not automatically as i know. In order to create client side validation you have to create an validator for the custom validation.
see following link for details on how to implement this: http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/729_Creating_Custom_Client_Side_Validation_in_ASP_NET_MVC_2_0.aspx

You have to create a DataAnnotationsModelValidator for the custom validation

Answer (score 12):

I usually use:

```
[RegularExpression("true")]
```

Comment: I like this one, though I had to tweak it this: `[RegularExpression("true|True")]` to get it work for me. (I'm using MVC3, if that makes a difference?)

Comment: did it give you client side validation as well ? got the server side correctly

Answer (score 6):

If you didn't want to create your own custom validator and still wanted to use existing attributes in the model you could use:

```
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage="You must accept the terms and conditions.")]
```

This ensures that the range of the boolean value is between true and true.  However, whilst this method will work, I would still prefer to use a custom validator in this scenario.  I just thought i'd mention this as an alternative option.

Answer (score 0):

I too am looking for a way to have the model binder correctly handle check boxes with Boolean values. In the mean time I'm using this in the Actions:

```
Object.Property = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["NAME"]);
```

Maybe this will be of some use to you.