# Understanding the $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool() method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to understand something.

From this blogpost http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

> Bridging HTML and jQuery Validate: Adapters
>
> **Writing a client-side validator involves two steps: writing the
>   validator for jQuery Validate, and writing the adapter which takes the
>   parameter values from the HTML attributes and turns it into jQuery
>   Validate metadata**. The former topic is not in the scope of this blog
>   post (since it’s really not MVC specific).
>
> There is an adapter collection available at
>   jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters. Hanging off the adapter
>   collection is the adapter registration method (add) and three helpers
>   that can be used to register very common types of adapters (addBool,
>   addSingleVal, and addMinMax).

Notice that it says **two** steps.

But if you take a look at this post [MVC3: make checkbox required via jQuery validate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934032/mvc3-make-checkbox-required-via-jquery-validate) you only need the second step ("writing the adapter") for the validation to work - by adding this line of code:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("mandatory", "required");
```

I tested out the code in a new MVC 4 Internet App and it works fine, here's the supersimple sample.

View Model

```
public class SimpleViewModel
{
    [Mandatory(ErrorMessage = "You must agree to the Terms to register.")]
    [Display(Name = "Terms Accepted")]
    public bool IsTermsAccepted { get; set; }
}
```

Validation Attribute

```
public class MandatoryAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return (!(value is bool) || (bool)value);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        rule.ValidationType = "mandatory";
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

View

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.SimpleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}    

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsTermsAccepted)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsTermsAccepted)
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("mandatory", "required");
    </script>
}
```

So basically I've got three questions:

1. is $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("mandatory", "required"); really the only thing you need besides writing an attribute class?
2. what exactly does it do behind the scenes?
3. where can I find good documentation about addBool?

Comment: 1: Only for "already existing" adapters. 2: Not sure, hoping to find out myself. 3: If you find one, please let me know!

Comment: http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/

Answer (score 3):

Besides the article @BlueChippy linked to in the comments, I found the answer to 2. in [this article](http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/validation-of-required-checkbox-in-asp-net-mvc/).

1. yes that's the only thing needed besides the attribute. That is because we use a rule that already exists (*required*).
2. What does it do?

> This just registers a new validation adapter for the *MandatoryAttribute*,
>   where the first parameter is the adapter name and the
>   second parameter is the name of jQuery validate rule. The adapter name
>   should match the value we specified earlier as the validation type,
>   and the jQuery validation required-rule will require the user to check
>   the checkbox.

3 . More information can be found in [this article on Brad Wilson's blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html).