# asp.net mvc - how do I validate a checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, annotations

I've found the model annotations very useful for the validation in MVC but can't seem to get it working for a checkbox. I am using MVC 3 with razor and c#.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to validate? That it is checked? Are you suggesting that a false value for your property is not a valid value? Is this a checkbox for a user to "check" in order to go to a next step like accepting a terms of service?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766952/how-would-you-validate-a-checkbox-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Answer (score 0):

Last time I heard this question, the customer wanted to verify whether the question had been answered or not.  This is not possible with a checkbox, and can only be done by using a pair of radio buttons for yes and no and defaulting both to unchecked.  Then when submitted, if neither button is checked, validation fails.